# Laravel routes malfunctioning

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm having some problems with a Laravel/Livewire project. I've been working on this project for a while and everything seemed to work fine.

The project is divided in 2 route files; one for the normal users, and one for the dashboard.

This is the dashboard route file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard\Welcome;
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard\Business;
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard\Subscription;
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard\Pepe;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



Route::get('/', Welcome::class)->name('dashboard.index');
Route::get('/business', Business::class)->name('dashboard.business');
Route::get('/subscription', Subscription::class)->name('dashboard.subscription');


Route::get('/user/invoice/{invoice}', function (Request $request, $invoiceId) {
    return $request->user()->downloadInvoice($invoiceId, [
        'vendor' => 'Your Company',
        'product' => 'Your Product',
    ]);
});
```

And this one the guests route file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShowBusiness;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShowBusinesses;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShowCategories;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/categorias', ShowCategories::class)->name('show.categories');
Route::get('/{category}', ShowBusinesses::class)->name('show.businesses');
Route::get('/{category}/{business}', ShowBusiness::class)->name('show.business');
```

(Both are correctly registred on the RouteServiceProvider):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::middleware('web', 'auth')
                ->prefix('dashboard')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

The thing is, today I open my project as I used to do, and when I try to access the dashboard, y see a 404 page. Also, I can't create any new routes, because they dont work.

I think the problem has to do with Apache or something related to the routes, because the Auth middleware created by Laravel isn't working.

Besides, and I don't know if this is of any help: I have 2 layout files on my views folder. I call one of then in the dashboard routes, and the other on the guests views. If I do that, the guests views work fine, but the dashboard views returns 404. If I use the ->layout method only in the dashboard routes, and remove the method from the guests views, Laravel loads the layout, but not the content.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard;


use Livewire\Component;


class Business extends Component{

    protected $listeners = ['render'];


    public function render(){
        return view('livewire.dashboard.business')->layout('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

I've also cleared cache from my routes, my app and my browser, and this is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\elportaldesalamanca\public"
    ServerName elportaldesalamanca.test
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\elportaldesalamanca\public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you tried clearing cache ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `RouteServiceProvider` try to change order your routes. `web` need to be last.

```
 /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web', 'auth')
                ->prefix('dashboard')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/dashboard.php'));
       

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
       });
     }
```

Because you have one route in your `web.php` which need to be last in your routes list. This route catch your "/dashboard" as category and returned 404 because you dont have "dashboard" category.

```
Route::get('/{category}', ShowBusinesses::class)->name('show.businesses');
```